# Excluding folders using Get-ChildItem -Exclude

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I require to exclude user profiles from `\\Computer\c$\Users` folder when using `Get-ChildItem`.

I potentially need to exclude 100 profiles from various machines so have created a variable that contains all user profiles from an AD security group that I want excluding but when I run the below command it doesn't work but if I list the profiles in plain text it does work.

```
Get-ChildItem "\\$computer\c$\Users" -Exclude $ListOfUsers
```

But works if I run `Get-ChildItem "\\$computer\c$\Users" -Exclude Bob1,Bob2,Bob3,Bob4,Bob5`

My code to obtain the users from AD security groups are below and the format it outputs to is like the above with commas.

```
## collects users from groups and adds to exlusion list.
$1stline =   Get-ADGroupMember GG_1st_Line_Team | Select SamAccountName
$2ndline =   Get-ADGroupMember GG_2nd_Line_Team | Select SamAccountName
$3rdline =   Get-ADGroupMember GG_3rd_Line_Team | Select SamAccountName
$FieldTech = Get-ADGroupMember  "Field tech" | select SamAccountname
$Excluded = $1stline + $2ndline + $3rdline + $Fieldtech | Out-File "C:\temp\Members.txt"
(get-content c:\temp\Members.txt) -join "," | out-file C:\temp\Format.txt
$format = get-content c:\temp\format.txt; $format = $format -replace '\s',''; $format = $format -replace ',SamAccountName,--------------,',''; $format = $format.trimend(",,") | Out-File "C:\temp\newFormat.txt"
$excluded = Get-Content C:\Temp\newFormat.txt
```

This will create a text file with 100 names with no spaces, only commas to seperate the users. If I `Write-Host` the variable `$newformat` the commas are White along with the text but if I put the Profile names in plain text then the commas are grey...

Comment: The list should look like this: `$excluded = @("Bob1", "Bob2", Bob3", "Bob4", "Bob5", "Bob6")`

Comment: `$excluded = 'Bob1,Bob2,Bob3,Bob4,Bob5'; $ListOfUsers = $excluded -split ','; Get-ChildItem "\\$computer\c$\Users" -Exclude $ListOfUsers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The excessive use of `Out-File` is unnecessary and will cause you issues as it changes objects into strings. You then have to use commands like `Split` and `Join` to turn the strings back into the object (arrays here) you require.

`Out-File` should only be used when you actually need the output *as a file*.

With a few simple changes to your script it'll do what you want, and be a lot simpler too!

---

You can use `ExpandProperty` to only return the value of `SamAccountName` itself as a string rather than an object.

You can then simply create an array of those strings and use this to exclude those accounts/folders from `Get-ChildItem`,

```
$1stline =   Get-ADGroupMember GG_1st_Line_Team | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
$2ndline =   Get-ADGroupMember GG_2nd_Line_Team | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
$3rdline =   Get-ADGroupMember GG_3rd_Line_Team | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
$FieldTech = Get-ADGroupMember  "Field tech" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountname

$excluded = $1stline,$2ndline,$3rdline,$Fieldtech

Get-ChildItem "\\$computer\c$\Users" -Exclude $excluded
```

---

You could then look into using a `foreach` loop with `Get-ADGroupMember` to cut down on the duplicated `Get-ADGroupMember` code.

Comment: C - Well that worked immensley. All that was required was -expandProperty

Comment: Please take my advice on not using `Out-File` too, it's going to help you write better code if you don't use it like you are trying to.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here seems to be that you're using a `[string]` variable with a value of `Tom,Dick,Harry`.

I bet you've got no folders like this, have you?

[image: Tom,Dick,Harry Folder]

Whilst you can pass a `[string]` in to the `-Exclude` parameter; that will be a singleton (a single, scalar value); and the best you'll get is a *single* exclusion.

What you really want to pass in is a string array: `[string[]]`!

```
[string]$excludedString = "Tom,Dick,Harry"
[string[]]$excludedArray = $excludedString -split ","
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\users" -Exclude $excludedArray
```

Comment: You are correct and I don't have a folder called Tom,Dick,Harry however I have separate profiles individually named Tom & Dick & Harry and for the -Exclude to work the correct format must be in a string with commas separating the names.

Putting quotations around each name seems to work but its becoming messy where I like your solution.

`$excluded = Get-Content C:\Temp\newFormat.txt;$excluded = $excluded -replace ',','","'`

that gives the output file as "Tom","Dick","Harry"

On a side note, is there a command I cna use to add a character to the end of the string? I need to add a "

Comment: Ok Get-ChildItem "\\$computer\c$\Users"  -Exclude $Excluded did NOT work.

$Excluded is now in this format "Tom","Dick","Harry". If I copy those names in plane text and not as a variable ($Excluded) then it works.... .something wrong with using a variable?

Comment: @JoeClough have you tried using `-split` to turn the string in to an array?

Comment: I have tried this `(get-content c:\temp\Members.txt) -split "," | out-file C:\temp\Format.txt` and this lists the members in a vertical column. this is not accepted as a correct format to use with -exclude

Comment: @JoeClough `$excluded = (Get-Content C:\temp\Members.txt) -split ","` then `Get-ChildItem... -Exclude $excluded`

Comment: @JoeClough `out-file` is converting the input object (an array here) into a format suitable for a text file. What you see in the output file is not the same as the input object.

Comment: Think I've done it.

'$excluded = Get-Content "C:\Temp\newFormat.txt"
$excluded = ([string] $Excluded).Split(",")
get-childitem \\Computer\c$\users -Exclude $excluded`